# ASP Repeater is causing html warnings in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2013

[image]
From the screenshot I can see here what the engineer who wrote this has attempted. Making use of an ASP repeater to create a list of elements in an unordered list.

It would seem that VS gets a little upset about this and can't figure out what's going off, so just shows HTML warnings.  Obviously this is not creating any issues when running, but those warnings are irritating me.  Is there a simple way to solve this or does this need writing in a different way to remove those warnings?

```
<form id="theForm" method="POST" class="form form-horizontal dirtyForms">
<input type="hidden" runat="server" ID="hiddenID" name="hiddenID" class="hiddenID" />
<input type="hidden" runat="server" ID="hiddenDialogID" name="hiddenDialogID" />
<input type="hidden" runat="server" ID="hiddenParentID" name="hiddenParentID" class="hiddenParentID" />
<input type="hidden" runat="server" ID="hidWorkflowID" name="hidWorkflowID" class="hidWorkflowID" />

<div class="uiModalBody clearfix" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <ul runat="server" id="tabsContainer" class="nav nav-tabs" style="left: 10px; position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 10px;"></ul>
    <div runat="server" id="tabPanelsContainer" class="tab-content" style="border: #ddd 1px solid; border-top: 0; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; margin-bottom: 0 !important; overflow-y: scroll; padding: 20px 20px; position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 48px;"></div>
    <span runat="server" id="Fields" class="TheFields" style="display:none"></span>
</div>

<div class="uiModalButtons clearfix">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="uiButton ModalClose"><span class="icon cancel">Cancel</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="submit" id="SaveButton" class="uiButton saveButton" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"><span class="icon save">Save</span></button>   
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repSave">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <div style="margin-left:-1px;display:inline-block;" class="dropup">
                        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="buildMenu uiButton">
                            <span style="display:inline-block;width:9px;height:17px;padding-right:0;" class="arrow"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul style="font-size:13px;" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                            <li><button type="submit" id="SaveButton" class="saveButton" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></button></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Edit : attached the markup

Comment: Could you rewrite that into using a ListView with LayoutTemplate and ItemTemplate?

Comment: Your markup is broken. From what I can see the `<fom>` tag is not properly closed and since you are working in WebForms it messes up the ASP.NET controls as well as the HTML elements.

Comment: Form tag looks properly closed ot me.  I've attached the markup so it a bit more clear.